# Wrapping div inside an if condition

Tags: php, if-statement, filter

So, I have the following div and I want to show it just if the item type is equal to "Mobile Phone" or Tablet, selected on the same page with a combo box (also an input but instead of writing it's a combobox), but I just can't figure it out how to wrap this div inside an if condition based on what is selected on the combo box, can anyone help me?
Something like this:
if item = "MobilePhone" or item = "Tablet" --------> Show div

But I have Php code already inside the div.. that's why i just can't do it

```
<div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($imeiError)?'error':'';?>">
                    <label class="control-label"><strong>IMEI</strong></label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input name="imei" type="text"  placeholder="IMEI" value="<?php echo !empty($imei)?$imei:'';?>">
                        <?php if (!empty($imeiError)): ?>
                            <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $imeiError;?></span>
                        <?php endif;?>
                    </div>
                 </div>
```

And that's how i select the input that I want

```
<div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($itemError)?'error':'';?>">
<label class="control-label"><strong>Item</strong></label>
<div class="controls">
    <select name="item">
        <option value="MobilePhone" <?php echo !empty($item) && $item == 'MobilePhone' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>MobilePhone</option>
        <option value="Tablet" <?php echo !empty($item) && $item == 'Tablet' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Tablet</option>
        <option value="Computer" <?php echo !empty($item) && $item == 'Computer' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Computer</option>
        <option value="HeadPhones" <?php echo !empty($item) && $item == 'HeadPhones' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>HeadPhones</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: You already have an `if` clause in your code, just place one around your `<div>` and you should be ready to go. Where exactly are you stuck? Your "_Something like this_" answers your question

Answer (score 0):

If your div has `display:none` in your css.

Use select's `onchange="myFunc()"`

And in your `myFunc()` look for selected value and do whatever you want. 
`document.getElementById('yourDivId').style='display:block'` sets your div visibility.

```
<select onchange="myFunction()" id="select"><!--selections with different values --></select>
<script> function myFunction() {
    var selected=document.getElementById("select").value;
  if(selected=="Mobile")
       document.getElementById("yourDivId").style="display:block";    }
</script>
```

Comment: I didn't get it

Comment: But it hasn't the condition there :/

Comment: What condition? The condition is on that if? Am I missing something?

Comment: I just want to show IMEI div if the selected on combobox is equal to "mobilephone" or "tablet" :/

Comment: `if(selected=="MobilePhone" || selected=="Tablet")` and set an ID for your div. Do not expect to get the full code from stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You already seem to be checking for `$item` in your second code, so assuming that `$item` is set you can use this code to show the div only if "MobilePhone" or "Tablet" is selected:

```
<?php if ($item == "MobilePhone" || $item == "Tablet") : ?>

<div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($imeiError)?'error':'';?>">
    <label class="control-label"><strong>IMEI</strong></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input name="imei" type="text"  placeholder="IMEI" value="<?php echo !empty($imei)?$imei:'';?>">
        <?php if (!empty($imeiError)): ?>
            <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $imeiError;?></span>
        <?php endif;?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: It keeps showing me this over and over and idk why...
Notice: Undefined variable: item in line 203
(line 203 is the first like that u wrote)

Comment: So where does `$item` in your second code come from? There should be something like `$item = $_POST['item']` (simplified) in your PHP file.

Comment: Yes, exactly like that! i have that code on the beggining of the page after i call the database.php

Comment: That was just a simplified version, you'd need to check if `$_POST['item']` is set etc. On the first call of your page it is not, so `$item` might not be set. You can do this!

Comment: Sorry to ask this.. but how can i properly set it?

Comment: I really didn't get how to set a var properly :/

Comment: can you explain me please?

Comment: NEVER trust user input and blindlessly take it into your code. `trim()` the var, strip unwanted chars, strip `<script>` tags, use [filters](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php), make sure `$_POST['item']` is set before assigning it.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you!!
but the var is set like       `$ativo = $_POST['ativo'];`                at the beggining of the code

Comment: Then use `$ativo` instead of `$item`. In your second code though you are mentioning `$item`. Good luck

Answer (score -1):

you can use a variable `$html` to organize `html` in `if` condition like below code.

```
 <?php 
    $item = "MobilePhone";
$html = "";
if ($item == "MobilePhone" || $item == "Tablet") {
$html .= '<div class="control-group';
        echo !empty($imeiError)?'error':'';
$html .= '<label class="control-label"><strong>IMEI</strong></label><div class="controls">
        <input name="imei" type="text"  placeholder="IMEI" value="'.!empty($imei)?$imei:''; '">';
      if (!empty($imeiError)): 
$html .= '<span class="help-inline">';
        echo $imeiError;
$html .= '</span>';
        endif;
$html .='</div></div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Your `if` clause is missing brackets. And a closing curly bracket. Comparison is done using `==`, not `=`. Concatenation is done using `.=`, not `+=`.

Comment: Error message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$ativo' (T_VARIABLE), expecting '(' in C:\... line 205
line 205: if $item = "Telemovel" || $item= "Tablet" {

Comment: It's `if ($item == "MobilePhone" || $item == "Tablet") {` as stated in my comment

Comment: I've uploded that rn but it keeps showing me the same error.. like the var is unknown..

Comment: Code: ` <input name="imei" type="text"  placeholder="IMEI" value="'. !empty($imei)?$imei:''; .'">' `

Error: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' **

Comment: @saddam it isn't working yet, it keeps showing me some errors like that one ^ :/

Comment: But $Item can't be equal to nothing that way, the user must have to select the item type :/